# Get redirect to another page from Hyperlink button in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one gridview in which i'm binding a List of Website names like

```
www.google.com
www.facebook.com
www.gmail.com
www.google.com
www.facebook.com
www.gmail.com
```

Now, I want to redirect to `www.google.com` when i click on this

I used this one but its not working

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Website", @"{0:hh\:mm}") %>' Text='<%# Eval("Website", @"{0:hh\:mm}") %>' Target="_blank"></asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: If you inspect the element using the dev tools in the browser what is the url for your hyper link?

Comment: Is it navigating to any page? If so try to include protocol http/https https://google.com

Comment: after inspect in browser its showing www.google.com but after click on that link its adding some extra website  name http://somtsitename.in/Masters/www.google.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include "http://" before your redirect link.Please go through the below example,

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Website","http://{0}") %>' Text='<%# Eval("Website") %>' Target="_blank"></asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

OR

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href="<%# Eval("Website","http://{0}") %>"><%# Eval("Website") %></a>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the `NavigateUrl` has `http://` or `https://` in it, otherwise the browser will think it is a link in the same domain.

```
NavigateUrl='<%# "https://" + Eval("Website", @"{0:hh\:mm}") %>'
```

Or if some website do have that http in them but others don't, you can check for that first

```
NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Website").ToString().Contains("http") ? Eval("Website") : "https://" + Eval("Website") %>'
```

Comment: after trying this i'm getting System.NullReferenceException how do i handlw this

Comment: Check for null first: `Eval("Website") != null && Eval("Website").ToString().Contains("http")`